# What is the asymptotic behavior of factorial

Tags: calculus, limits

The question of the asymptotic behavior of $n!$ when $n\to\infty$ usually arises in calculation of time complexity for algorithms and relates to calculation of the following limit.

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln(n)}$$

At the first sight, I figured out that it is an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminate form. I found it hard to use the L'Hopital rule, so I decided to solve this via founding some bounds on $\ln(n!)$. First, I noted that

$$\ln(n!)=\ln(n\times(n-1)\times\dots\times 1)=\ln(n)+\ln(n-1)+\dots+\ln(1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(i)\tag{1}$$

and consequently

$$\int_{1}^{n}\ln(x)dx<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(i)\lt\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(n),\tag{2}$$

where I used the fact that $(1)$ is an upper Reimann sum for the shown integral. Simplifying $(2)$ yields

$$n\ln(n)-n+1<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(i)\lt n\ln(n).\tag{3}$$

Dividing by $n\ln(n)$ leads to

$$1-\frac{1}{\ln(n)} + \frac{1}{n\ln(n)} <\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln(n)}\lt 1,\tag{4}$$

Finally, I used the sandwich theorem for limits to get

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln(n)} = 1$$

Is my approach OK? What are other ways to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your titular question:

$$n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(1+\frac{1}{12n}+\cdots\right)$$

A nice truncation of the latter series (the "Stirling series") due to Ramanujan is:

$$n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\sqrt[6]{8n^3+4n^2+n+\frac{1}{30}}$$

But you can omit the tail series for an asymptotic approximation in the right-half complex plane if I remember correctly (it becomes a somewhat divergent series, losing accuracy as more terms beyond a certain number are given in the left-half plane) and the most commonly seen version is just $n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$. Certainly the series is good for the real axis.

So:

$$\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln n}\sim\frac{n\ln n-n+\ln(\sqrt{2\pi})+\frac{1}{2}\ln n}{n\ln n}=\frac{n+1/2}{n}+\frac{\ln(\sqrt{2\pi})-n}{n\ln n}$$

From which convergence to $1$ is clear.

Your approach was ok, and certainly more direct!

For further reading see "[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)" which can be proved in general for the Gamma function. The full series can be derived from [Binet's formulae for the log-gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html).

For real positive $x$, and complex $z$ restricted off the negative real axis (although it does diverge...): $$\begin{align}\ln(\Gamma(x+1))=\ln(x!)&=(x+1/2)\ln x-x+\frac{1}{2}\ln2\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2n}}{2n(2n-1)}x^{1-2n}\\&=(x+1/2)\ln x-x+\frac{1}{2}\ln2\pi+\left(\frac{1}{12x}-\frac{1}{360x^3}+\frac{1}{1260x^5}-\cdots\right)\\\Gamma(x+1)=x!&=x^xe^{-x}\sqrt{2\pi x}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{1}{12x}-\frac{1}{360x^3}+\frac{1}{1260x^5}-\cdots\right)\\&=x^xe^{-x}\sqrt{2\pi x}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{12x}+\frac{1}{288x^2}-\frac{139}{51840x^3}+\cdots\right)\end{align}$$

Where $B_n$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) (positive or negative it doesn't matter).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your attention. I didn't know there is such a formula! So, I should dig into proving this Ramanujan formula too. :) By the way, it seems that you made a typo in the third equation as there should be any $\ln n$ next to $\frac{n+1/2}{n}$

Comment: @HoseinRahnama Yes good catch. I'll add in the general form of the series so you can have a go with showing Ramanujan's version (I warn you, without a CAS to do the number crunching it is quite tedious!)

Comment: @HoseinRahnama More detail + the full series has been added. Good luck! Calculating the binomial expansion of $\sqrt[6]{8x^3+4x^2+x+1/30)}$ is not quick :) I should also add that Ramanujan's truncation is brilliant in the sense that is extremely accurate for small $x$ as well, not merely as an asymptotic tool

Comment: Although trying to prove the series' correctness is in itself quite hard; Binet's formulas are non-trivial. One way to show it is through [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242521386_An_Elementary_Proof_of_Binet's_Formula_for_the_Gamma_Function) paper (there is the occasional typo/incorrect equality in this paper but all its major results and methods are correct)